# Motorola Bug Why is this not centering

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm going crazy with this...why won't this center I have tried almost all the centering options in combinations and such but the darn text and password field won't center!  It works fine on MyTouch 4G but al my Motorola phones its acts like this...

I call the dialog with a basic call

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.preference_dialog);
dialog.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.stringLoginTitle));
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

Here is what the dialog layout looks like in Eclispe

[image]

And here is what it looks like when shown as a Dialog.

[image]

Dialog layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_LoginTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/stringLoginPassword" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_LoginTitle"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_AdminOkay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_AdminCancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
    android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this on all my Motorola phones X2, Razr...Seems to definitely be a bug in the styles for Motorola.

I fixed it by creating my own style and copying panel_background from my \android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-hdpi and placing it in my drawable.  Eclipse wouldn't compile if I referenced it using @android:drawable/panel_background.

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

Then just call the dialog with the Theme parameter added

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
```

There fixed Motorola issues!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to make the same layout I would have used linearlayout...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_LoginTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/stringLoginPassword" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="center" />


    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_AdminPassword"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_AdminOkay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Login" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_AdminCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work, and I copied and pasted your code directly!

Comment: I tried my code on my phone and everything is center aligned..  as expected.. 
Strange !!

Comment: Was a co-incident you can see the xml are diffent just the approach was same.. I think you can understand this is a common approach come first in mind.

Comment: I wonder if its an OS/Phone issue?  I am running it on a Motorola X2, hmm, same on Razr using 2.3.6 android, but on MyTouch 4G Slide its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout has an XML property android;layout_alignCenter, you might try that on the first textview and then align the rest to the textview.

Comment: Already did seems its a OS/Phone specific issue... works fine on a MyTouch 4G, but not on my Motorola phones.

Comment: Wow.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.